# How to upload multiple .csv files to PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using pgAdmin in PostrgreSQL to work.

There are 10 .csv files with 10 different tables on my computer. All 10 tables represent the same type of data, it's just divided into 10 different months. Basically I need one table with all the months. But first I was thinking about creating 10 tables and import 10 .csv files and then combine them together into 1 single table.

I perform the following algorithm to create 1 table: create the table, create the column names, set the data types in each column, import the .csv file into the table. Then I repeat the same operation 9 times for the rest of the .csv files. Is there any way to upload all 10 files with one step? Thank you

Comment: Seems like an odd request.  If you have ten tables, you have ten "processes" that you need to execute.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Got it. I just edited the question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Load the data all into one table.  You can use `copy` or concatenate the files together outside the database.